# Appending Stylesheet via javascript without flickering

Tags: javascript, css

I have a default CSS code for my page. I am injecting a CSS stylesheet file into the bottom of the `head` that overrides the default one using JavaScript. For some reason when I load the page, I see the default one and then it overrides it with the loaded stylesheet,

What can I do so that flickering will not occur? I thought that if I add a CSS at the end of the head after the default one I won't see the flickering because the content is not loaded yet, but apparently, it is. Any solution for that?

I don't know if flickering is the right word, I just see the default CSS and immediately after I see the page with the overridden CSS. Furthermore, maybe it's relevant, the overridden CSS only overrides some of the elements not all of them.

Here is the code:

```
<head>
<link href="/Content/app.min.css?ver=17" rel="stylesheet" />

<script>
    // dark theme
    if (localStorage.getItem("current_theme") === "dark") {

        var head = document.head,
            link = document.createElement('link');

        link.type = 'text/css',
            link.rel = 'stylesheet',
            link.href = '/Content/dark_theme.min.css?r=' + 
                        (Math.floor(Math.random() * 20000) + 1);

        head.appendChild(link);

    }
</script>

// the JavaScript appended stylsheet will render here before the </head> element
</head>
```

What happens is that the change of the new CSS happens only after the page has been loaded. I put a breakpoint in the footer, and only after the page is loaded I see the new CSS update.

I've found out that this happens because the stylesheet file is loaded asynchronously and therefore the delay. I need to inject the CSS code inline to make it work. The problem is with that approach is that it adds 9KB to each page call instead of dynamically based on the localStorage variable value.

Comment: what causes the flicker in your case? is it the font? you could try moving the stylesheet at the start of head as well.

Comment: @gauravmuk I just see the page as it in the default css, a second later I see the colors changing as in the injected CSS. Maybe flicker is not the right word, it just that I see the default first and the change after. I shouldn't see the page until all the CSS is loaded, including the second one, but for some reason I see the change after the page is loaded.

Comment: When is your JavaScript executed? If that is executed at pageload (so technically after pageload), then the new CSS will only take effect AFTER the default CSS has already been loaded. I think you need to look for something like that, that will explain the issue.

Comment: Does the issue occur if you manually add the new sheet to the bottom of the page without JS?

Comment: @myfunkyside I will add the code to the question in a second.

Comment: @IdanShechter have you tried inlinig some of ur css? maybe ur classes are getting appended late? classes are within html or js is injecting them or some other library?

Comment: @gauravmuk the classes are appended with the default CSS.

Comment: i mean the classes are within HTML or some JS code is adding them to dom?

Comment: @gauravmuk the classes are within the HTML, not JS code modifications. The body background color which is the most basic change I can see the transition between the default and the overridden CSS.

Comment: Have you tried putting the `<script>` at the very top of the `<head>` ? Maybe it's actually just caused by the time that is needed to append the new `<link/>` and load the CSS reference file etc.

Comment: @myfunkyside the javascript code in the head should prevent the process of the body content until it finishes processing the code, at least that what I understand. What happens in practice, is that the change of the theme happens only after the page is loaded.

Comment: I understand, I mean put the script at the very top, before the first`<link/>` element. Just to see what happens. *Basic rules of experimentation: alter parameters and observe any changes.*

Comment: @myfunkyside what I was thinking, the CSS file is loaded asynch. I need to inject the CSS code itself into the head inline for it to work.

Comment: Good to know. Damn this would be so easy with a PHP session-var, but that of course has its own downsides..

Comment: @myfunkyside actually that what I was thinking, but the problem is that I am caching the whole page in ASP.NET output cache, so I can't do that unless I am changing all the structure of the user controls on the page.

Answer (score 2):

The following code works faster:

```
<head>
<link href="/Content/app.min.css?ver=17" rel="stylesheet">

<script>
    // dark theme
    if (localStorage.getItem("current_theme") === "dark")     
        document.head.innerHTML += '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/dark_theme.min.css">';
</script>
</head>
```

But your approach is wrong.

You'd better use a cookie for this stuff. Save the theme name to the cookie. Read cookie from request headers and include the required css right on the server side. So the client receives:

```
<head>
    <link href="/Content/app.min.css?ver=17" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/dark_theme.min.css">
</head>
```

Also I'd recommend setting correct Expires headers on the server and getting rid of ugly `?ver=17` or `?r=(Math.floor(Math.random() * 20000) + 1)`

Comment: `ver=17` has a number of advantages over expires headers, but otherwise the rest of the answer is spot on.

Answer (score 0):

The flickering issue you're experiencing when dynamically adding a new stylesheet might be due to the fact that the browser needs to re-render the page with the new styles, causing a momentary flicker.

To this instead:

Create a new link element, set its attributes, and then append it to the head. This way, the browser applies the styles more smoothly:

```
var linkElement = document.createElement("link");
linkElement.rel = "stylesheet";
linkElement.type = "text/css";
linkElement.href = style_url;

linkElement.onload = function() {
    // The stylesheet has been loaded
};

document.head.appendChild(linkElement);
```